# Why properties previous circle in canvas is getting replaced with newer properties?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have canvas, where I wanted to draw one inner and just above it one outer circle. First of some weired line is shown between in circle. Secondly, I want `lineWidth` of outer circle as 5, it is also making outer circle with as 5. 
How to stop this?

My code,

```js
    <script>
        function drawCircle() {
            var circleCanvas = document.getElementById("myCircleCanvas");
            var circle = circleCanvas.getContext("2d");
            circle.beginPath();
            var x = 95;
            var y = 75;
            var radius = 60;

            circle.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            circle.stroke();

            circle.fillStyle = '#505050';
            circle.fill();
            circle.fillStyle = '#fff';

            var font = "bold " + radius / 3 + "px serif";
            circle.font = font;
            circle.fillText("AVAYA", x - x / 3, y - y / 5);

            circle.fillStyle = '#000';
            circle.fillText("CIE", x - x / 3 + 15, y - y / 5 + 25);

            circle.arc(x, y, radius + 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            circle.lineWidth = 5;//just want to increase outer circle
            circle.stroke(); //why drawing extra line
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<canvas id="myCircleCanvas">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
        </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the two circles to be treated independently, close the path that you started and begin a new one before you draw the second circle.  For instance:

```
function drawCircle() {
    var circleCanvas = document.getElementById("myCircleCanvas");
    var circle = circleCanvas.getContext("2d");
    circle.beginPath();
    var x = 95;
    var y = 75;
    var radius = 60;

    circle.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    circle.stroke();

    circle.fillStyle = '#505050';
    circle.fill();
    circle.fillStyle = '#fff';

    var font = "bold " + radius / 3 + "px serif";
    circle.font = font;
    circle.fillText("AVAYA", x - x / 3, y - y / 5);

    circle.fillStyle = '#000';
    circle.fillText("CIE", x - x / 3 + 15, y - y / 5 + 25);

    circle.closePath();
    circle.beginPath();

    circle.arc(x, y, radius + 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    circle.lineWidth = 5;//just want to increase outer circle
    circle.stroke(); //why drawing extra line

    circle.closePath();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mudbo48j/1